# Pretty MuPad: Output of assignment, expression and result in one line - How to create that function?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, computer-algebra-systems, mupad

I'm trying to get Matlabs's MuPad as pretty  and convenient as MathCad.

Assume two variable assignments:

```
x_a:=2*unit::mm;
y_b:=5*unit::mm;
```

and I want a prettyfied (typeset with Tex) output like

```
z = x_a + y_b = 7 mm
```

I already managed to do so by using `output::mathText(...)`:

```
output::mathText(hold(z)," = " , (z:=hold(x_a+y_b)) , " = " , z)
```

which looks as desired:

[image]

But this is not really convenient and not readable. So I'm trying to wrap it into a macro or a function:

```
evalPrint(z,x_a+y_b)
```

**How can I do that?**

---

What I tried:

I wrote a procedure as follows:

```
evalPrint :=
proc(x,y) begin
  output::mathText(hold(x)," = " , (x:=hold(y)) , " = " , x)
end_proc:
```

but I just get

[image]

**What am I missing?**

---

Regarding [horchler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753288/2605073): his first solution does somehow not work, while the second does:

procedures:

```
evalPrintVal := proc(x,y) option hold;
begin
    output::mathText(x, " = ", evalassign(x,y));
end_proc:
evalPrintEq := proc(x,y) option hold;
begin
    output::mathText(x, " = ", evalassign(x,y), " = ", context(y));
end_proc:
evalPrintEq2 := proc(x,y) option hold;
begin
    output::mathText(x, " = ", y, " = ", evalassign(x,y));
end_proc:
```

call:

```
evalPrintVal(U_1,15000*unit::V);
evalPrintEq(E_h, U_1*1.05);
evalPrintEq2(E_h, U_1*1.05);
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem of [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). MuPAD is no different from most other programming languages in that methods/functions/procedures have a limited [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping). The [`DOM_VAR`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom_var.html) domain type refers to a local variable of a procedure (a bit more [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/variables-inside-procedures.html#progfund-variables-inside-procedures-closures)). You can't directly see the name of a variable before it's passed into a Matlab function (use [`inputname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) for this), and MuPAD is no different. Additionally, arguments are normally evaluated *before* they get passed into the functions or procedure.

Luckily, the fix is pretty easy in terms of coding. First, you need to use the [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/proc.html#ex5b) option for your [`proc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/proc.html). This appears to both prevent evaluation of input arguments and allow access to "the actual parameter in the form that was used in the procedure call." Then you need to use [`context`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/context.html) to evaluate the last part of your output. The resultant procedure looks like this:

```
evalPrint := proc(x,y) option hold;
begin
    output::mathText(x, " = ", y, " = ", context(y));
end_proc:
```

Then

```
x_a := 2*unit::mm;
y_b := 5*unit::mm;
evalPrint(z, x_a+y_b);
z;
```

returns

[image: MuPAD output one]

However, since this was done in a procedure, the value of `z` wasn't assigned a value in the global scope like in your inline expression. To handle this, the [`evalassign`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/evalassign.html) function can be used:

```
evalPrint := proc(x,y) option hold;
begin
    output::mathText(x, " = ", evalassign(x,hold(y)), " = ", context(y));
end_proc:
```

which now returns `7 mm` for `z` like your inline expression:

[image: MuPAD output two]

This form works as well and is slightly more concise:

```
evalPrint := proc(x,y) option hold;
begin
    output::mathText(x, " = ", y, " = ", evalassign(x,y));
end_proc:
```

Tested in R2015a.

Comment: This already looks very promising, I will try it as soon as I can. And thanks for the interesting links, I kind of have a hard time finding these information for Mupad.

Comment: It works nicely. I'd keep this open a little longer, so your extensive answer can get some more attention? And as you seem to be a Mupad expert, maybe you're interested in helping me with my [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786164/define-general-relative-search-path-for-custom-mupad-procedures).

Comment: actually your first solution does not work (see my edit), but the second does. I don't see the reason why the first works in your case and in mine not.

Comment: @thewaywewalk: That's because I had a bug in my first version. Fixed now. The second version is definitely simpler and easier to understand – I'd use that one. Thanks for finding this.