# Define general relative search path for custom Mupad procedures

Tags: matlab, mupad

Imagine I have a mupad-notebook **myMupadNotebook.mn** at the path `'C:\projectFolder\ABC\abc\'`. It calls the procedure **MyMupadProcedure.mu** which is located at `'C:\DEF\GHI\'`.

Now I have a Matlab script **main.m**  at `'C:\projectFolder\XYZ\xyz\'` with the content:

```
nb = mupad('C:\projectFolder\ABC\abc\myMupadNotebook.mn');
status = evaluateMuPADNotebook(nb);
```

So it initializes a symbolic engine and executes the Mupad script. But the Mupad script requires to know where to find the procedure. So I can define some start-up commands (or a start-up script) within the Mupad Notebook with **File->Properties->Start-up commands** like this:

```
READPATH := "C:\DEF\GHI\";
read("MyMupadProcedure.mu");
```

---

**But now I work on different machines and the absolute folder paths are different, but the relative paths are the same.** How can I use my scripts on all machines?

In Matlab I'd just set the **SearchPath** on every machine and it works, is there something equivalent for Mupad?

---

Alternatively it would already help if I could pass a string from Matlab to Mupad and I'd just write the start-up commands in the header of my notebook and determine the relative path with Matlab functions. But all combinations of the following lines just do not work:

```
syms X
X = 'hello'
setVar(nb,'X',X)
evalin(nb,['X := "' X '"'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could think the integration of MuPad into Matlab is much better.

The direct transfer from variables and strings from Matlab to MuPad, apart from symbolic expressions (`setVar`), does not seem to be possible. Correct me if I'm wrong. However it is possible to write files in Matlab with a relative path and read files in MuPad with a relative path.

This way it is possible to write the path, where the MuPad procedures are stored, into a textfile - located in the same folder, where the MuPad Notebook is executed:

```
%// determined with pwd, cd and string manipulation etc
MuPadNotebookPath = 'C:\projectFolder\ABC\abc\' 
MuPadProceduresPath = 'C:\DEF\GHI\';    

fid = fopen( [MuPadNotebookPath  '\parameters.txt'], 'w'); 
fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n%', strrep(MuPadProceduresPath ,'\','\\')); %'
fclose(fid);
```

Now there will be a file **parameters.txt** in `'C:\projectFolder\ABC\abc\'`.

In MuPad the **environment variable** [**`NOTEBOOKPATH`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/notebookpath.html) can be used to get the directory of both the **parameters.txt** and **myMupadNotebook.mn**.

[**`ftextinput`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/ftextinput.html) can then be used to read to path `'C:\DEF\GHI\'` from the text file. Finally the [**`READPATH`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/readpath.html) can be set.

```
cfgfile := NOTEBOOKPATH . "parameters.txt":
rpath = ftextinput(cfgfile, rpath):
READPATH := rpath:
read("MyMupadProcedure.mu");
```

In total it looks like:

```
nb = mupad(MuPadNotebookPath);
fid = fopen( [MuPadNotebookPath  '\parameters.txt'], 'w'); 
fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n%', strrep(MuPadProceduresPath ,'\','\\')); %'
fclose(fid);
status = evaluateMuPADNotebook(nb);
```